# SQL Server, create password field MD5

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a little problem in SQL Server - how to create a table to encrypt password in MD5, I don't know how to declare the column in SQL Server.

[password problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZM0t.jpg)

Can someone help me? I'm creating a MVC application just for practice.

Comment: MD5 can be decrypted. You'd be better off with salted and hashed passwords.

Comment: Do you mean store the password hash? A hash is a binary value so the appropriate data type is varbinary.

Answer (score -1):

The internal MD5 Function of SQL will return a String with 32 hex characters. So you can use a field type where you can store a String with at least 32 Chars. For example CHAR(32).

Comment: This ignores the fact MD5 is not a cryptographic hash, was never designed for, and should never be used for, password hashing.

Comment: Note that for newer versions of SQL Server, it will also raise a deprecation warning. Ideally you should avoid using deprecated features as they will stop working in a future release.

Comment: Thats true. But he only needs it for practice. But please use a real hash function in a live version.

Comment: Ty for the answer guys, yes im just practicing , nothing serious

Comment: But if you're practicing, you should be practicing the *right* way.